# dplyr: apply function table() to each column of a data.frame

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

#### Apply function table() to each column of a data.frame using dplyr

I often apply the table-function on each column of a data frame using *plyr*, like this:

```
library(plyr)
ldply( mtcars, function(x) data.frame( table(x), prop.table( table(x) ) )  )
```

Is it possible to do this in *dplyr* also?

My attempts fail:

```
mtcars %>%  do( table %>% data.frame() )
melt( mtcars ) %>%  do( table %>% data.frame() )
```

Comment: You could convert this to `long` form using `gather` from `library(tidyr)` and then do `gather(mtcars, Var, Val) %>% group_by(Var) %>% dplyr::mutate(n=n()) %>% group_by(Var,Val) %>% dplyr::mutate(n1=n(), Percent=n1/n)%>% unique()`

Comment: can you post a full answer using this approach

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Using tidyverse (dplyr and purrr):**

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
    map( function(x) table(x) )
```

Or:

```
mtcars %>%
    map(~ table(.x) )
```

Or simply:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
    map( table )
```

Comment: Using the purrr anonymous function syntax, that would be `mtcars %>% map(~table(.))`

Answer (score 13):

You can try the following which does not rely on the `tidyr` package.

```
mtcars %>% 
   lapply(table) %>% 
   lapply(as.data.frame) %>% 
   Map(cbind,var = names(mtcars),.) %>% 
   rbind_all() %>% 
   group_by(var) %>% 
   mutate(pct = Freq / sum(Freq))
```

Comment: can you elaborate the answer. I am getting some errors due to worse input data.frame and would like to troubleshoot. can I use purrr:map  and not `Map`  error is `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`

Answer (score 11):

In general you probably would not want to run `table()` on every column of a data frame because at least one of the variables will be unique (an `id` field) and produce a very long output. However, you can use `group_by()` and `tally()` to obtain frequency tables in a `dplyr` chain. Or you can use `count()` which does the `group_by()` for you.

```
> mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    tally()
> # mtcars %>% count(cyl)

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  cyl  n
1   4 11
2   6  7
3   8 14
```

If you want to do a two-way frequency table, group by more than one variable.

```
> mtcars %>% 
    group_by(gear, cyl) %>% 
    tally()
> # mtcars %>% count(gear, cyl)
```

You can use `spread()` of the `tidyr` package to turn that two-way output into the output one is used to receiving with `table()` when two variables are input.

Comment: `mtcars %>% count(cyl)` or `mtcars %>% count(gear, cyl)`.  I think the question is how to do this for every variable in one call.

Comment: Fair enough; but I just wanted to point out that usually running this on every single column will result in really, really long output. At least one of the columns is likely to be a unique id variable. I updated my answer to include the use of `count` since it does the `group_by` for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Caner did not work but from comenter akrun (credit goes to him), this solution worked great. Also using a much larger tibble to demo it. Also I added an order by percent descending.

```
library(nycflights13);dim(flights)

tte<-gather(flights, Var, Val) %>% 
group_by(Var) %>% dplyr::mutate(n=n()) %>% 
group_by(Var,Val) %>% dplyr::mutate(n1=n(), Percent=n1/n)%>%
arrange(Var,desc(n1) %>% unique()
```